# Do Rust's borrowing rules get in the way of functional data structures?

Tags: rust, borrowing

Functional data structures (such as the Hash Array Mapped Trie used in Haskell/Clojure/Scala) rely on lots of sharing in the underlying data structure. For example, if we implement `insert` on a map-like data type that's usually implemented by path-copying on the tree that implements the data structure.

Given that these data structures rely a lot on sharing (and no principal owner of) underlying values, will borrowing get in the way of implementing such structures?

Comment: As phrased, this question seems overly broad or opinion based. Have you tried something and had it not work? Are you aware of the "escape hatch" that `unsafe` provides? What kind of answer would be valid here? There's a [hamt crate](https://crates.io/crates/hamt/), does that provide an answer?

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227269/generic-types-ownership-and-persistent-data-structures?rq=1). It explains that `Rc` allows multiple owners of the same data, and while it might look like `.clone()` does a copy, it's a shallow copy that doesn't actually copy the data. It's actually immutability that allows this to happen. The hamt crate uses `Rc` [here](https://github.com/rainbowbismuth/hamt-rs/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L801).

Comment: Shared immutable ownership is generally simple by making GC explicit. Cyclic data is the problematic part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short Answer: **No**.

Long Answer:

Rust actually works very well with immutable structures (it gives more guarantees than C's `const` for example).

The shared ownership is no problem (`Rc`/`Arc`) with a truly immutable value, and you can easily borrow multiple times into an immutable structure. You cannot move while borrowing, but this can be circumvented by handing out owning proxies (via `Rc` or `Arc` once again) instead of references.

The one issue in Rust that you may not have in Haskell is mixing mutable values in with `Cell` or `RefCell` as you can then create cycles and those won't be collected because Rust has no GC.